# how to have a directory dialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, file-browser

In PyQt, how does one display a file browser that shows and selects only directories (not files)?

And how does one retrieve the name of the selected directory?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

From inside your QDialog/QWidget class, you should be able to do:

```
file = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))
```

Comment: from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

Comment: self is your parent QWidget

Comment: from PySide2.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

Comment: If the above isn't working for you. It's the issue with your widget. pass `None` instead of `self` and it will work, like this:
```folder = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select Directory"))```

Answer (score 22):

Just as simple as that:

```
folderpath = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select Folder')
```

Here, `self` represents the parent window usually the `QMainWindow` object.

#### Similarly for File dialog:

```
filepath = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Hey! Select a File')
```

Comment: up  voted!!! very well explained and compared with the ```QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Hey! Select a File')```

Comment: what if I want either directory or file?

Answer (score 0):

In PyQt6 `QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory` is the same as PyQt5, but things change for `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName` which returns a tuple instead:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
file_path, filter_ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Pick a file')
```