# PyQt - assign to a button the ability to choose a directory

Tags: python, pyqt

I am having trouble searching for the method to assign to a Push Button the ability to choose a directory. I found this [how to have a directory dialog in Pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286036/how-to-have-a-directory-dialog-in-pyqt), but I am still unsure about the method.

For example, I have a push button called `new_directory` and I have this code `self.new_directory.clicked.connect(self.pick_new)`. What do I need to put into the function `pick_new` so that when `new directory` is clicked I can choose a new directory and have this stored in a variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might help you.
With this you can get the directory.

```
def pick_new():
    dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
    folder_path = dialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select Folder")
    return folder_path
```

Comment: Thanks. Was using PyQt5 so I had to make a small adjustment to QtWidgets. Much appreciated!