# Get text from FileDialog Python\Qt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, maya, pymel

I'm pretty new with Qt in Python, and I need to know how could I get from a file dialog one directory path and show it in a text box inside my ui.

```
class ControllerLibraryUI(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ControllerLibraryUI, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Controller Window')
        self.buildUI()

    def buildUI(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        textWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        textLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(textWidget)
        layout.addWidget(textWidget)
        self.saveNameField = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        textLayout.addWidget(self.saveNameField)
        btnWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        btnLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(btnWidget)
        layout.addWidget(btnWidget)
        importBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Import')
        importBtn.clicked.connect(self.load)
        btnLayout.addWidget(importBtn)
        closeBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Close')
        closeBtn.clicked.connect(self.close)
        btnLayout.addWidget(closeBtn)

    def load(self ):
            filename = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0]
            print filename
    def showUI():
        try:
            ui.close()
        except:
            ui = ControllerLibraryUI()
            ui.show()
            return ui

ui = showUI()
```

This is the basic concept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to have a directory dialog in Pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286036/how-to-have-a-directory-dialog-in-pyqt)

Comment: No, that's just part of the question

Comment: Use `self.saveNameField.append(filename)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the file dialog :

```
directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select directory')
```

and then you assign the directory variable to the setText method from your text box

Comment: I was using the QtWidget.QFileDialog, is it different?

Comment: Or this one str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()

Comment: it is the same it is just a difference between pyqt5/pyqt4

Comment: also the same for qfiledialog, you didn't provide any code so I've put something with standard arguments. If you are not using class, you can get rid off the self

Comment: I add the code, the basic idea, sorry for the format but from the phone it's impossible to do better. I add difficult to show the text in the textbox e resize the textbox to a line instead of a big square